# Keeping lawn out of garden beds

Tags: lawn, grass, border

I have buffalo grass for lawn and garden beds around the house. The grass wants to spread into my garden bed. I have a border of concrete curves that looks like this:

[image: Concrete Border Image]

But the border is fairly overgrown.

What's the best way to keep lawn out of gardens?

Is there a grass that is recommended? Perhaps a non-invasive variety.

Or should I just maintain the border better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having that concrete border actually makes this a much easier task than many of us (I have no separator, so it requires constant work)

Two simple steps:

- Regularly through the growing season, use an edging tool to go around the grass edge of the concrete, cutting vertically through anything trying to grow beyond that demarcation line.
- Where seeds have landed in your beds and are growing, regular turning of the soil in the beds, as you would do anyway for weeding purposes, will be sufficient

You shouldn't need anything more serious than that.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get your hands on some cedar sawdust, cedar chips, or cedar bark mulch, that will suppress grass quite well.

I'd put a trench along the grass side of your concrete barrier, and fill it with cedar sawdust.

Comment: How wide and deep should the trench be? I have a mechanical edger and can easily make a trench 5cm (2") deep and wide. Will that suffice? Also, will cedar sawdust keep back invasive grasses like buffalo and couch.

Comment: 2" would be a good start, but grass roots can go under that. Better would be 10 cm each direction, if you can. That's not too hard to do with a square-bottom shovel.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok for some digging, dig a narrow trench along your concrete strip (grass side) with a mattock. Then install the one foot wide root barrier plastic that comes in rolls. Once this bit of hard work is done you will never have strong grass invade the garden beds.

Comment: This is interesting. I would love to vote up your answer but it needs more info. How wide would it have to be? In a "U" shape or an "I" shape? Also consider adding a picture of or link to an example of the product you mentioned.