# Building a concrete divider for a lawn/garden bed

Tags: lawn, grass, concrete, border

I have a garden bed in between my fence and my lawn, seperated by a row of two bricks in an "L" arrangement.

I'd like to replace the bricks with a concrete divider similar the picture in [this post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/keeping-lawn-out-of-garden-beds) - a curved concrete 'rail' with a 'step'.

The shape of my garden bed is very similar. 
Is this a DIY task I'd be able to achieve by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, the concrete blocks are too heavy.

---

I asked the question you reference and while the picture isn't my own, the concrete blocks I have are exactly the same. The blocks themselves are fantastic, easy to mow over and wide enough to keep out my invasive grass (most of the time) - buffalo.

This is a great DIY task and an excellent improvement, mine look great. But unless you're a weight lifter, you would need at least **2** people. I'm a big, (I like to think) strong guy and those block are **HEAVY**! I would say they're around 40-50kg (100lb) and about 100 cm (40in) long. I broke a shovel trying to dig out out, snapped the handle in half! I moved 4 and it just about killed me.

Do yourself a favour and get a mate to help you out.

Good thick gloves are a must and a mattock helped me.

Comment: Oh - I was thinking it was a pour the concrete yourself deal.  Do you know the name of the product/method?  I've been trying to google it, but nothing I've found is very similar; probably the wrong search terms.

Comment: Found it, eventually.  "Preformed concrete edgers" and "Garden edging"  were the winners.  Cheers very much!

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I was looking to buy more of it but I didn't know the name myself. I had a look at the local Bunnings and they didn't have it... :( I recommend having a look in the Trading Post, often people will give it away if you're willing to pick it up.

Comment: @Daniel I just had a Google, there are many varieties of preformed concrete edgers. Don't get something that is too vertical, you'll need to use a line trimmer to get down low on it. Get something that you can run the tyres of your lawn mower up... like in the picture. Also you might want to have a look at this question : http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/5445/608

Comment: My brick setup actually works okay for the mowing, so I'll be using something of a similar height.    They have a huge problem with weeds though, hence the switch.  I did see that link, I'll definitely be trying the staining once I'm set up.  Cheers again!